# Why isn't time calculating correctly?

Tags: java, android, time, long-integer

I am trying to do a a simple time calculation where i display elapsed time in a textbox.  The problem is that my approach is returning a value of zero when it should be returning something else.  Is it possible for longs to be cast to ints for this purpose? Any help is appreciated.

My Code:

total_hours_paycycle is a long that has a value of 259200000.  And is showing as such in debugger

```
        try{
            int total_minutes = (int) ((total_hours_paycycle/ (1000*60)) % 60); //<--Should return non-zero value, but is returning 0
            int total_hours   = (int) ((total_hours_paycycle/ (1000*60*60)) % 24);  //<--Should return non-zero value, but is returning 0
            hours_worked_converted = total_hours + "." + total_minutes; //<--returning 0.0  
            total_for_paycycle.setText("Total: "+hours_worked_converted + " hrs."); 
        }catch(Exception e){
            total_for_paycycle.setText("Total: - ");
        }
```

Comment: Why do you expect the first calculation to return 12? (25920000000 / 60000) % 60 = 0.

Comment: when total_hours_paycycle = 4320000 it returns 1 hour and 12 minutes.  i don't understand why 25920000000 returns zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mist of this, I recommend you take a look at [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). It's usually way better to do date math and it takes into consideration often overlooked issues like Timezones, daylight times, etc.

It may be too much, but the jar is small and it will help you with any date/time related operation you have.

Plus it's used by hundreds of apps, so it works.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use android's [TimeUnit](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) class if you are working for API level 9 and above:

```
    int total_minutes = (int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds);
    int total_hours = (int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliseconds);
```